# Pandas dataframe column from data containing NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The following code transforms a given pandas column `FEAT` into a new, binary feature named `STREAM`. The program works as long as there are no NaN values in the original dataframe. If that is the case, the following exception occurs: `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`.
I need to push the NaN values to the new column. Is it doable? 
Here is the code option that fails:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {
    'FEAT': [8, 15, 7, np.nan, 5, 2, 11, 15]
}
customer = pd.DataFrame(data)
customer = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['June', 'Robert', 'Lily', 'David', 'Bob', 'Sally', 'Mia', 'Luis'])
#create binary variable STREAM 0:mainstream 1:avantgarde
stream_0 = [1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12, 14]
stream_1 = [2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
# convert FEAT to list_0
list_0 = customer['FEAT'].values.tolist()
# create a list of length = len(customer) whose elements are:
#  0 if the value of 'FEAT' is in stream_0
#  1 if the value of 'FEAT' is in stream_1
L = []
for i in list_0:
    if i in stream_0:
        L.append(0)
    elif i in stream_1:
        L.append(1)
# convert the list to a new column of customer df
customer['STREAM'] = L
print(customer)
```

Comment: what's value does it get in the `else` block, which is missing (i.e. not in stream_0 or stream_1)

Comment: Absolutely, I was indeed missing the else. thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are missing an `else` block so when a value (like `NaN`) is in neither `stream_0` nor `stream_1` you do nothing which then causes L to have fewer elements than the number of rows in `customer`.

Looping here is unnecessary, `np.select` can handle the column creation. The `default` argument will handle the `else` block.

```
customer['STREAM'] = np.select([customer.FEAT.isin(stream_0), customer.FEAT.isin(stream_1)],
                                [0, 1], default=np.NaN)

        FEAT  STREAM
June     8.0     0.0
Robert  15.0     1.0
Lily     7.0     1.0
David    NaN     NaN
Bob      5.0     0.0
Sally    2.0     1.0
Mia     11.0     1.0
Luis    15.0     1.0
```

---

You could also map the few values, everything not in either is `NaN`

```
d = {key: value for l,value in zip([stream_0, stream_1], [0,1]) for key in l}
customer['STREAM'] = customer['FEAT'].map(d)
```

The dict uses a comprehension to create the key value pairs. For every key in `stream_0` we assign it a value of `0`, for every key in `stream_1` we assign a value of `1`. The comprehension is a bit complicated, so a more easy to understand method which accomplishes the same would be to create each dictionary separately, then combine them.

```
d_1 = {k: 0 for k in stream_0}
d_2 = {k: 1 for k in stream_1}
d = {**d_1, **d_2}  # Combine
#{1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: 1, 7: 1,
# 8: 0, 9: 1, 10: 0, 11: 1, 12: 0, 13: 1, 14: 0, 15: 1}
```

Comment: the second solution WORKS. However, it is very cryptic. Can you explain  a bit more or provide an easier-to-understand code. Thanks

Comment: @josephpareti I added some explanation, and also a more straight forward way to create the dictionary. It's a bit more typing but I think clearer. [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) uses that dict to transform the values

Comment: thank-you, I understand more the option with the 2 dictionaries, but I still do not understand d = {**d_1, **d_2}

Comment: @josephpareti See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-in-python. In python 3.5+ it's one very concise way to merge dictionaries otherwise you can use `dict.update`